# I want to install a psql module, but ubuntu cannot find the package?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, installation, git

I wanted to install a postgres module in ubuntu similar to [this](https://github.com/dimitri/prefix). So I ran a `sudo apt-get update` and that ran fine. Next, I did a `sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.2-prefix` just like the instructions stated, but all I got was this error:

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.2-prefix
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package postgresql-9.2-prefix
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'postgresql-9.2-prefix'
```

Could someone be kind enough to tell how to locate the package? By some chance, if the package isn't located in ubuntu's repo, how do I know what repo to add? Isn't that github thing a repo already? So theoretically I could add it in my software sources? (I could be totally wrong though lol.) I am using Ubuntu 11.10.

Comment: check here, hope it helps. http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/dists/

Answer (score 0):

You'll have a hard time installing anything on Ubuntu 11.10, since it is no longer supported. Unless you switched repositories, I doubt apt will work at all. I suggest upgrading to Ubuntu 12.04 (still supported for many years) and installing [postgresql-9.1-prefix](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/postgresql-9.1-prefix).